# Ring with both laws of composition equal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I can't seem to figure out the following proposition:
Let $A$ be a ring with equal laws of composition, that is, $a+b=ab$ for every $a,\ b \in A$. Show that $A = \{0\}$.

Comment: Let $b = 0$ for instance.

Answer (score 0):

$a\in A\implies a=a+0=a(0)=a(a-a)=a^2-a^2=0$